# Putting pictures in to header

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have two pictures in my wordpress header, but these pictures are broken. How or where I need to put these pictures..

I created folder C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\images and there is 2 images, but how I get these in to my header.

I already tried:

```
<div style = 'position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px;'>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/et/'><img src='estonia.jpg' /></a>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src='english.gif' /></a>
        </div>
```

and

```
<div style = 'position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px;'>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/et/'><img src='C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\images\estonia.jpg' /></a>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src='C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\images\english.gif' /></a>
        </div>
```

and

```
<div style = 'position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px;'>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/et/'><img src='images\estonia.jpg' /></a>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src='images\english.gif' /></a>
        </div>
```

But its not working, what im doing wrong ??

Can somebody help me ? Thanks !

Comment: in which folder is this file?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\themes\customizr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images should generally go in a `your-theme-name/images` folder. What you're doing isn't necessarily wrong but it can lead to confusion down the line.

You can use [`<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to get the current's template directory path. This is used for when your current theme is a child theme.

You can also use [`<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>`](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-dynamically-get-theme-directory) which will return the current template directory. If you're using a child theme, it will return the uri to the parent theme, not the child.

Long story short, you can use it like this for no child:

```
<a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/image-name" /></a>
```

And like this for a child theme:

```
<a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image-name" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add these pictures to a header theme? When editing a Wordpress theme I think you have to find the original theme header file in the theme folder in the wp-content folder.

C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\themes\ (the name of your theme folder)